# Checking for an existing element with specific id in CKeditor Instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

when my page load i try to check for elements wether they exits in a specific instance of Ckeditor But i am getting the error can not read the property of undefined. My code if Following..

```
function defaultChecked(Ids){
    var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances['terms_id'] ;
    for(var i = 0; i<Ids.length; i++)
        {
            element =   oEditor.document.getById(Ids[i]);   
            if(element)
                {
                console.log(Ids[i]);    
                }
        }
    }
var Ids =   ['t1','t2','t3','t4'];
defaultChecked(Ids);
```

i am using the same method `getById()` successfully in following function on onClick event in same file.

```
function changevalue(id){ 
            var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances['terms_id'] ;
          if(jQuery('#'+id).attr('checked'))
          {
            terms   =   jQuery('#item'+id).html(); 
            var htmlString = jQuery( '#item'+id ).text( htmlString ); alert(htmlString);
            oEditor.insertHtml('<span id='+id+'>&nbsp;'+htmlString+'<span>');
            }
          else
            {
               element  =   oEditor.document.getById( id );element.remove();
           }
}
```

Comment: There's no `editor.getById()` method so this code is incorrect: `CKEDITOR.instances['terms_id'].getById('t1')`. Just remove the `getById()` call and it should work if you don't have other bugs.

Comment: Sir i have tried the same like you explained but the same error is there and  my second function in my code it works well which is called on onClick event